# Capistrano v3 and Rails migration, precompile and bundle issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy an app on a DigitalOcean prebuilt Rails app (unicorn, nginx).

Everything work fine with the standard capistrano v3 recipy, but when i add the following modules to perform migration, bundle install and precompile assets:

`require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'`

I get a

`DEBUG [4f5bfce9] Command: cd /home/rails/releases/20140307184517 && ( RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [4f5bfce9]    bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
DEBUG [4f5bfce9]`

which is where i am totally stuck now :S

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the copy of bundler that is being referenced is trying to use ruby 1.8 that does not exist.

Can you check the contents of `/user/local/bin/bundle`?